# Textinput in Shiny - How to cancel autocomplete

Tags: r, shiny

I use textinput:

```
 textInput("password_input", label=h4(":pass"),value = "", width = "50%")
```

[image]

and I want to cancel the autocomplete that show me the last choices

any suggetion?

Comment: Use passwordInput? https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/passwordInput.html

Comment: TY, but I've the some problem with the username field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use `passwordInput` we can use [htmltools::tagQuery](https://rstudio.github.io/htmltools/reference/tagQuery.html) to set [autocomplete = "off"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion):

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagQuery(textInput("test", "test"))$find("input")$addAttrs("autocomplete" = "off")$allTags()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

*Edit:* for multiple textInputs:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

tq <- tagQuery(fluidPage(
  textInput("test1", "test1"),
  textInput("test2", "test2")
))

ui <- tq$find("input")$addAttrs("autocomplete" = "off")$allTags()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

If there are other inputs in the expression, which we don't want to modify, we can find the `textInput`s via class `shiny-input-text`:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

tq <- tagQuery(fluidPage(
  textInput("text1", "text1"),
  dateInput("date1", "date1"),
  textInput("text2", "text2")
))

ui <- tq$find(".shiny-input-text")$addAttrs("autocomplete" = "off")$allTags()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

*Another Edit:* using JS (make sure to place the snippet below the relevant inputs):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text1", "text1"),
  dateInput("date1", "date1"),
  textInput("text2", "text2"),
  tags$script(
    HTML(
      "
      const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('shiny-input-text');
      for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        collection[i].setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
      }
      ")
  ),
  textInput("text3", "text3 is not modified")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you don't want the JS snippet's position to influence which inputs are modified, we could trigger it via [shiny:sessioninitialized](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/js-events/):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(
    HTML(
      "$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
        const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('shiny-input-text');
        for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
          collection[i].setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
        }
      });"
    )
  ),
  textInput("text1", "text1"),
  dateInput("date1", "date1"),
  textInput("text2", "text2"),
  textInput("text3", "text3 is also modified")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn off autocomplete for all textInputs?

Comment: @mat the above also works for multiple `textInput`s just make sure to wrap them in the same `tagQuery` call and set a proper selector. Please see my edit.

Comment: Many thanks! I wish there was a simpler way to achieve this without having to wrap the whole UI into a tagQuery. Something like adding a simple jQuery script in the header, or by adding a class to the textInput

Comment: Sure - the same can be done via JQuery or JS. I edited once again.

Comment: Awesome! To go one step further, would that approach work if the textInputs are dynamically generated via `uiOutput`? I gave it a try with one of my projects but it didn't work. But maybe it is because of another unknown reason.

Comment: @mat  the JS script can only modify elements already existing in the DOM. You could re-trigger it after creating new inputs (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)) or directly modify them on creation e.g. using the above `tagQuery` call or via `htmltools::tagAppendAttributes`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will have a look into it!